# Python: Weird result while indexing the dictionary from collections.Counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

Let's say I have a list of numbers

```
numbers = ['3', '3', '4', '4']
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of the elements in the list, so I use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

result = Counter(numbers)

result
Counter({'3': 2, '4': 2})
```

Here's something that I find quite funny, if you try to index the Counter, it will always show 0 no matter what number of index you put into it.

```
result[0]
Out[22]: 0

result[1]
Out[23]: 0

result[100]
Out[24]: 0

result[10000000000]
Out[26]: 0
```

Any idea of this interesting results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes the counter collections inherits from dict and has a missing method implemented

part of the code of the counter

```py
class Counter(dict):
    '''Dict subclass for counting hashable items.  Sometimes called a bag
    or multiset.  Elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts
    are stored as dictionary values.
    '''

    def __missing__(self, key):
        'The count of elements not in the Counter is zero.'
        # Needed so that self[missing_item] does not raise KeyError
        return 0
```

The dict type will always try to call **missing**. In case of the counter always returns `0`

See the [`dict` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> **`d[key]`**
> Return the item of *d* with key *key*. Raises a `KeyError` if *key* is not in the map.
>
> If a subclass of dict defines a method `__missing__()` and *key* is not present, the `d[key]` operation calls that method with the key *key* as argument. The `d[key]` operation then returns or raises whatever is returned or raised by the `__missing__(key)` call. No other operations or methods invoke `__missing__()`.

When you do

```
result[10000000000]
>>> 0
```

you are not indexing the counter but accessing to the keys when the key is not present the count for that key is 0

```
result["a"]
>>> 0
```